# Custom container ViewController flag isMovingToParentViewController not works

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am trying to implement my own container ViewController and faced interesting issue.

First of all I have read a lot about implementing container ViewController:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

I have added VC like this:

```
[self addChildViewController:newChildViewController];

NSLog(@"%@", @(newChildViewController.isMovingToParentViewController));

[self.view addSubview:newChildViewController.view];

NSLog(@"%@", @(newChildViewController.isMovingToParentViewController));

[newChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Output is:

```
0
0
```

Same with removing child VC and `isMovingFromParentViewController` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to apple docs:

> This method returns YES only when called from inside the
>   viewWillAppear: and viewDidAppear: methods.

This is true for both `isMovingFromParentViewController` and `isMovingToParentViewController`methods.

Check details here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingToParentViewController